# Java Android - iText - writeSelectedRows with cellEvent

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a table at a specific position in a PDF I open.
I created a table and added a few cells to it, then i used writeSelectedRows.
This code works when i only use Phrases but when I use a "MyCellField" to add an event, it doesnt work.

This is my code :

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/fiche_chantier.pdf");

        //Create time stamp
        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "Prevision_");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdir();
        }

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder + timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);

        PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{PageSize.A5.getWidth()});
        table.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
        table.setLockedWidth(true);

        MyCellField nomProprietaire = new MyCellField("nomProprietaire");
        PdfPCell cellNomProprietaire = new PdfPCell();
        cellNomProprietaire.setCellEvent(nomProprietaire);

        Phrase nomDonneurOrdre = new Phrase("My Text Here");
        PdfPCell cellNomDonneurOrdre = new PdfPCell(nomDonneurOrdre);

        Phrase adresseDonneurOrdre = new Phrase("My Address Here");
        PdfPCell cellAdresseDonneurOrdre = new PdfPCell(adresseDonneurOrdre);

        //table.addCell(cellNomProprietaire);
        table.addCell(cellNomDonneurOrdre);
        table.addCell(cellAdresseDonneurOrdre);
        /*table.addCell(cellNomProprietaire);
        table.addCell(cellNomProprietaire);*/

        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 155, 610, canvas);
        pdfStamper.close();
```

And the "MyCellField" class:

```
    class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
            protected String fieldname;
            public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
            }
            public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle,  PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
                final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
                final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
                try {
                    final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
                    writer.addAnnotation(field);
                } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
                } catch (final DocumentException de) {
                   throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code works, but when I add the table.addCell(cellNomProprietaire) lines, the app crashes.
Do you have an idea ?
Thank you,
Corentin

EDIT1: Stack Trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.piveteau.pivforet, PID: 12900
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported in this context. Use PdfStamper.addAnnotation()
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.addAnnotation(PdfStamperImp.java:1312)
                 at com.piveteau.pivforet.tools.SelfNoteFragment$MyCellField.cellLayout(SelfNoteFragment.java:67)
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:599)
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:829)
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:962)
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:908)
                 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:887)
                 at com.piveteau.pivforet.tools.SelfNoteFragment.createPdf(SelfNoteFragment.java:176)
                 at com.piveteau.pivforet.tools.SelfNoteFragment.onActivityCreated(SelfNoteFragment.java:95)
                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Is this what you want ? I'm not sure to know how to get Stack trace.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: Is this what you want ? I'm not sure to know how to get Stack trace.

Comment: This is wrong: `final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();` The `PdfWriter` is actually a `PdfStamperImp` instance and it's not allowed to use the `addAnnotation()` method on `PdfStamperImp`. I think I have solved this problem once in another question, but I don't remember the solution. In any case: you need a `PdfStamper` instance and a page number to add an annotation in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Bruno Lowagie's comment, I created a instance variable pdfStamper and i use it in MyCellField class :

```
class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
        protected String fieldname;
        public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
        }
        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
            final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
            try {
                final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
                pdfStamper.addAnnotation(field, 1);
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
            } catch (final DocumentException de) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked for me, thank you for your help !